# Expose a local interface of an ejb on WebLogic server

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, ejb-3.0, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I'm trying to deploy an application on Oracle Java Cloud Service.
I created a stateless ejb (3.0):

```
@Stateless(name = "PTOnlineSessionEJB", mappedName = "ejb/PtOnlineBean")
@Local(PTOnlineSessionEJBLocal.class)
public class PTOnlineSessionEJBBean implements PTOnlineSessionEJBLocal {
```

with a local interface:

```
@Local
public interface PTOnlineSessionEJBLocal {
```

then I try to access to the ejb:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "PTOnlineService", portName = "PTOnlineServiceSoap12HttpPort")
@BindingType(SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
public class PTOnlineService {
    @EJB(name = "ejb/PtOnlineBean")
    PTOnlineSessionEJBLocal PtOnlineBean;
```

When I try to deploy on cloud server I get this error:

```
Caused by: weblogic.deployment.EnvironmentException: [J2EE:160200]Error resolving ejb-ref 'ejb****' from module 'PTOnlinev6-ViewController-context-root' of application 'PTOnline'. The ejb-ref does not have an ejb-link and the JNDI name of the target bean has not been specified. Attempts to automatically link the ejb-ref to its target bean failed because no EJBs in the application were found to implement the 'it.enigen.pt.online.ejb.PTOnlineSessionEJBLocal' interface. Please link or map this ejb-ref to its target EJB and ensure the interfaces declared in the ejb-ref are correct.
```

How can I expose and use an ejb with local interface on weblogic?

Comment: Have you tried `@EJB(beanName = "PTOnlineSessionEJB")`?